# Is it possible to share iCloud Notes with non-Apple device users?

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app

Similar to how I can create a doc on Google drive and get a shareable link that allows anyone with that link to view the content.

Is there a way that I can send a link to someone who doesn't have an Apple device so that they can view a note that I've created in the Note application?

Comment: Why not just send them a text message?

Comment: too long for a text message

Comment: Okay, if it's to long for a text message then put it in an email (or a doc attached to an email) and send it to them.

Answer (score 1):

The web app for iCloud notes is quite accessible cross platform. I don’t think you can invite a random non-iCloud account, but have you tried that?

I do know photo sharing works for people on Linux / windows (pc and phone) and android using web version of the iCloud photos, so notes or files might be next to ship.

Worst case, get them to create an AppleID / iCloud and you’ll be able to collaborate with them going forward even if Apple doesn’t open up notes sharing more widely outside of registered accounts.